# Checking Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to learn eigenvalues/eigenvectors.

I am using R to check my understanding.

I have am using a symmetric correlation matrix as my data set.

When I calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, I try to check the relationship:

$AX=\lambda X$

I assume, $X$ are the eigenvectors, a matrix, and the $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues, a vector.

Wouldn't $\lambda X$ result in a 1x3 matrix?

Next, if I turn $\lambda$ into a 3x3 diagonal, I don't get the left-hand and right-hand sides of the equations to match.

```
> m <- matrix(
+     c(  1, .9, .7,
+         .9,   1, .4,
+         .7, .4,   1),nrow=3
+ )
> 
> eigenvalues <- eigen(m)$values
> eigenvalues
[1] 2.35363603 0.61601660 0.03034736
> eigenvectors <- eigen(m)$vectors
> eigenvectors
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.6436239 -0.1110798  0.7572381
[2,] -0.5766348 -0.5801800 -0.5752248
[3,] -0.5032303  0.8068782 -0.3093652
> 
> diag(eigenvalues) %*% eigenvectors
            [,1]        [,2]         [,3]
[1,] -1.51485632 -0.26144143  1.782262974
[2,] -0.35521658 -0.35740049 -0.354348030
[3,] -0.01527171  0.02448663 -0.009388418
> m %*% eigenvectors
          [,1]       [,2]         [,3]
[1,] -1.514856 -0.0684270  0.022980180
[2,] -1.357188 -0.3574005 -0.017456556
[3,] -1.184421  0.4970504 -0.009388418
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Note that $\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues-they are numerical values and not vectors. Following that line of thought, $\lambda_n X$ will give you the same dimension as the corresponding eigenvector.

Comment: is $\lambda X$ saying to multiply the scalars across the rows of $X$?

Comment: $\lambda_n X$ means multiply the scalar $\lambda$ by every element of the vector $X$. The following link may be helpful-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication